# BIRT Summation Button disabled

Tags: eclipse, birt

In the BIRT Edit Chart dialog in Eclipse, on the Select Data tab, the Y-series Summation button is always disabled.

This has been the case ever since we upgraded our Development environments to Eclipse Neon 4.6.2, Java 8_121, and BIRT 4.6.0.

It "used to work" in our old environment (Eclipse Luna 4.4.2, BIRT 4.4.2, Java 8_91)

How can we regain the Summation functionality?

[image: partial screen-grab of disabled button]

Answer (score 0):

Our work-around does not enable the button, but produces the functional behavior of summing:

- Click the XML Source tab in the main report design editor;
- In the XPath /model/Axes/AssociatedAxes/SeriesDefinition/Series add the XML snippet:

  ```
    <DataDefinition>
      <Definition>1</Definition>
      <Grouping>
        <Enabled>true</Enabled>
        <GroupType>Text</GroupType>
        <AggregateExpression>Sum</AggregateExpression>
      </Grouping>
    </DataDefinition>
  ```